# How to show dynamic images with different resolution in circle like google?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to show dynamic images with different resolution in circle like Google ?
i tried this using bootstrap class class="img-circle" but it will work for some images with resolution of 304*236. But if the resolution of image is different it will not come properly(It will come in oval shape or square with curved edge).

My scenario
1. User select his profile pic from his local system.
2. Save the image in server
3. Show the profile image in circle

1. Can any one tell me how to show images with different resolution in circle ?
2. Or should i force the user to select only images with a particular size to select as profile pic?
3. Or can i do some code to crop the image and save ?
4. How can i allow user to crop the image and how can i save that in server.

My project is using ASP.net MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-box">
        <div class="profile-picture" style="background: #fff url('URL-IMAGE') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover;">
        <a href="#" class="btn active" style="width:100%;height:100%;">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.profile-box {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.profile-box .profile-picture {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```